# TS2306: File './*.js' is not a module

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to import a .js file into a typescript file.
Yes, I know... I've looked at other questions as well but I'm not able to figure this one out.

The .js file is generated using [canopy](https://github.com/jcoglan/canopy), and it looks like this:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

   ......

   var exported = { Grammar: Grammar, Parser: Parser, parse: parse };

   if (typeof require === 'function' && typeof exports === 'object') {
      extend(exports, exported);
   } else {
      var namespace = typeof this !== 'undefined' ? this : window;
      namespace.URLP = exported;
   }
})();
```

I've declared typings for it:

```
declare namespace URLP {
  function parse(input: any, options?: any): void;
}

declare module '*.js';
```

My tsconfig.json has:

```
"module": "esnext",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"importHelpers": true,
"noImplicitAny": true,
"suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
"target": "es5",
"typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
"lib": ["es2018", "dom"],
"allowJs": true
```

If I import the .js file using `import { URLP } from './urlp.js';` this throws the following error:

```
error TS2306: File '..../urlp.js' is not a module.
```

Odd enough, I can load the web app and make use of the URLP.parse() method in the browser.

If I try to import it using `import './urlp.js'`, I get no compilation errors, but in the browser URLP becomes undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means you didn't `export` anything in your JS file. Instead, you used the global `exports` (or `module.exports`) object. Try using the `require` syntax instead:

```
const { URLP } = require('./urlp.js');
```

Note that this prevents TypeScript from doing static code analysis to determine what's exported at compilation time, so everything you use from your external JS file will not be typed at all.

If you have errors like `Cannot find name 'require'.`, use `declare function require(path: string): any;`

Comment: const { URLP } = require('./urlp.js'); still gives me URLP as undefined in the browser

Comment: You have to bundle all of the files in one single file in order to run it in a browser. Did you do it already?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to use this in an angular 9 app. I've created another intermediate urlp_wrapper.js file in  which I do an import * as URLP from './urlp.js', then I use the URLP.parse method in a wrapper function that  I export. Later I import the wrapper function using const {wrapper_urlp} = require('urllp_wrapper.js') in typescript. This seems to work. But can't understand why it doesn't work without the intermediate js file.